# Showing my own app to open a file downloaded from internet - Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Hi everyone from Swift world!

I wonder How can I show my app in the list of available apps to open (or save) a file from internet. It like Dropbox or Whatsapp do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can be helpful:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Comment: This is what you want https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/